# THE JOSEPHUS PROBLEM? (concrete mathematics)

Tags: algorithm, math

"thanks in advance to give your precious time..."

In our variation, we start with n people numbered 1 to n around a circle, and we eliminate every second remaining person until only one survives.

As it is said that the smart mathematicians are not shame of thinking small..!

so we will start with the group of only 10 people around the circle.

The elimination order is 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, and 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, so 5 survives. The problem: Determine the survivor's number, J(n).

We just saw that J(10) = 5. We might conjecture that J(n) = n/2 when n is even; and the case n = 2 supports the conjecture: J(2) = 1. But a few other small cases dissuade us | the conjecture fails for n = 4 and n = 6.

```
  n =| 1| 2| 3|4 |5 |6 
_____|__| _|_ |_ |_ |_
J(n)=|1 |1 | 3| 1| 3| 5
```

as for n=1 there is no second person to eliminate so it is clear that the J(1)=1; and for the n=2 as the 2 is next to the 1 in the circle so the second(2) person get's eliminated i.,e n=2; J(2)=1 clear and fine ..!but for 3 persons in the circle the 2nd gets eliminated and we have 1,3 as the survivor but ,why the book show's that J(3)=3...
here i am unable to understand why for n=3 ;J(3)=3 as and for n=4 ;J(4)=1 and for the n=6;J(6)=5

Comment: https://oeis.org/A006257  *"In base 2 n-a(n) is equal to n with all digits reverted (leading zeros not considered). For instance a(43)=23 -> 43 is 101011, 43-23 = 20 is 10100. " (Paolo P. Lava)* and *"a(n) = 2*(n - 2^floor(log_2(n))) + 1" (Gregory Pat Scandalis)*

Answer (score 0):

We know every second person (which is the person immediatly after the person we are currently looking at) will be killed.

For `n = 3`:

```
  (1) 2  3        (looking at 1, kills 2)
   1    (3)       (looking at 3, kills 1)
        (3)        3 survives
```

For `n = 4`:

```
  (1) 2  3  4       (looking at 1, kills 2)
   1    (3) 4       (looking at 3, kills 4)
  (1)    3          (looking at 1, kills 3)
  (1)                1 survives
```

For `n = 6`:

```
  (1) 2  3  4  5  6      (looking at 1, kills 2)
   1    (3) 4  5  6      (looking at 3, kills 4)
   1     3    (5) 6      (looking at 5, kills 6)
  (1)    3     5         (looking at 1, kills 3)
   1          (5)        (looking at 5, kills 1)
              (5)         5 survives
```